# Unity Vuforia Extension EXC_BAD_ACCESS with AVCaptureSession

Tags: ios, objective-c, unity-game-engine, vuforia

So I am using Unity 2017.2.0f3 with the Vuforia Extension, and I imported the project in an extant iOS project following the https://github.com/blitzagency/ios-unity5 tutorial. The extant iOS project included a view in which you can toggle between an AR view which uses Vuforia, and a native iOS AVCaptureSession which can scan barcodes. The former works without error, but as soon as I try to do `session.addInput` or `session.addOutput` the latter feature crashes with:

`EXC_BAD_ACCESS`

within the `com.apple.avfoundation.videodataoutput.bufferqueue` Queue. 
I tried to use NSZombie to learn more about what kind of object was trying to be sent a message, but i can only run the application on a physical device, and thus I can't learn more about the actual object it tries to send a message to which causes the crash.

My reasoning is that it may have to do with Vuforia persisting a reference to a freed VIdeoDataOutput Buffer Queue which is triggered by my creation of a new `AVCaptureSession` with an `AVCaptureOutput` and an `AVCaptureInput`. What is tricky is that I don't know how to actually ascertain this or not since it is a third party library. The only ViewController which has an Objective-C wrapper is called `CameraCapture.mm` but this seems to be a vestigial Unity only View Controller, since any `NSLogs` or breakpoints I put in that method are not called.

```
private func setupCamera() {
    guard let device = AVCaptureDevice.defaultDevice(withMediaType: AVMediaTypeVideo),
        let input = try? AVCaptureDeviceInput(device: device) else {
            return
    }

    if session.canAddInput(input) {
        session.addInputWithNoConnections(input)
    }

    previewLayer = AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer(session: session)
    previewLayer.frame = self.view.bounds
    previewLayer.videoGravity = AVLayerVideoGravityResizeAspectFill
    view.layer.addSublayer(previewLayer)
    cameraPreviewView.layer.addSublayer(previewLayer)
    let metadataOutput = AVCaptureMetadataOutput()

    if session.canAddOutput(metadataOutput) {
        session.addOutputWithNoConnections(metadataOutput)

        metadataOutput.setMetadataObjectsDelegate(self, queue: DispatchQueue.main)
        metadataOutput.metadataObjectTypes = metadataOutput.availableMetadataObjectTypes
    } else {
        print("Could not add metadata output")
    }
}
```

Once the above method is called, even after calling the `AppDelegate` function from the blitz tutorial `appDelegate.stopUnity()` always crashes the app.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So basically the error I was getting was from Unity not truly exiting when in background. This is a setting which is configurable for iOS Unity exports in Unity itself. If you go to Edit> Player Settings> and then in the Inspector on the right under **Other Settings** there is a field called *Behavior In Background*. My original export had this set to *Suspend* and this caused the AVCaptureSession intrinsic to a Camera in Unity/Vuforia to not be probably cleaned up, in terms of its videoOutput delegate buffer, when Unity wasn't running, thus the resulting `EXC_BAD_ACCESS` when thinking I had Unity stopped and starting a new `AVCaptureSession`. So by switching *Behavior In Background* to *Exit* and then guaranteeing in my app that I had called `appDelegate.stopUnity()` before doing setting up input/output pairs for a new `AVCaptureSession()` successfully fixed the issue.